# How to upload image in reactjs using formik

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, formik, yup

How can I upload image in reactjs and store it to the mysql database im using formik form
this is the code i found in the other question in stackoverflow but why i get an error for my code can anyone can help me with my problem

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import axios from 'axios';


function Registration() {


    const initialValues = {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        address: "",
        gender: "",
        email: "",
        number: "",
        adminType: "",
        image: "",
        username: "",
        password: "",
    };

    const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        firstName: Yup.string().min(2).required(),
        lastName: Yup.string().min(2).required(),
        address: Yup.string().min(10).required(),
        gender: Yup.string().min(4).max(6).required(),
        email: Yup.string().min(10).required(),
        number: Yup.number().min(11).max(11).required(),
        adminType: Yup.string().required(),
        image: Yup.mixed()
                .required("You need to provide a file")
                .test("fileSize", "The file is too large", (value) => {
                    return value && value[0].sienter <= 2000000;
                })
                .test("type", "Only the following formats are accepted: .jpeg, .jpg, .bmp, .pdf and .doc", (value) => {
                    return value && (
                        value[0].type === "image/jpeg" ||
                        value[0].type === "image/bmp" ||
                        value[0].type === "image/png" ||
                        value[0].type === 'application/pdf' ||
                        value[0].type === "application/msword"
                    );
                }),
        username: Yup.string().min(3).max(20).required(),
        password: Yup.string().min(2).max(20).required(),
    });

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        axios.post("http://localhost:3001/auth", data).then(() => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            if (reader.readyState === 2) {
                this.setState({file: reader.result})
            }
        } 
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        console.log(this.props.fieldname);
        this.props.sfv("image1", event.currentTarget.files[0]);
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Registration</h1>
            <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
                onSubmit={onSubmit}
            >
                <Form>
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <ErrorMessage name="firstName" component="span"/>
                    <Field
                        autoComplete="off"
                        id="firstName"
                        name="firstName"
                        placeholder= "First Name"
                    />
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <ErrorMessage name="lastName" component="span"/>
                    <Field
                        autoComplete="off"
                        id="lastName"
                        name="lastName"
                        placeholder= "Last Name"
                    />
                    <label>Address</label>
                    <ErrorMessage name="address" component="span"/>
                    <Field
                        autoComplete="off"
                        id="address"
                        name="address"
                        placeholder= "address"
                    />
                    <label>gender</label>
                    <ErrorMessage name="gender" component="span"/>
                    <Field
                        autoComplete="off"
                        id="gender"
                        name="gender"
                        placeholder= "gender"
                    />
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <ErrorMessage name="email" component="span"/>
                    <Field
                        autoComplete="off"
                        id="email"
                        name="email"
                        placeholder= "email"
                    />
                    <label>Number</label>
                    <ErrorMessage name="number" component="span"/>
                    <Field
                        type="number"
                        autoComplete="off"
                        id="number"
                        name="number"
                        placeholder= "number"
                    />
                    <label>Admin Type</label>
                    <ErrorMessage name="adminType" component="span"/>
                    <Field
                        autoComplete="off"
                        id="adminType"
                        name="adminType"
                        placeholder= "admin"
                    />
                    <label>Image</label>
                    <ErrorMessage name="image" component="span"/>
                    <input
                        autoComplete="off"
                        id="image"
                        name={this.props.Image}
                        type="file"
                        onChange={this.imageHandler}
                    />
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <ErrorMessage name="username" component="span" />
                    <Field
                        autoComplete="off"
                        id="username"
                        name="username"
                        placeholder="Ex. guko"
                    />
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <ErrorMessage name="password" component="span" />
                    <Field
                        autoComplete="off"
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        placeholder="Ex. guko1234"
                    />
                    <button type="submit">Register</button>
                </Form>
            </Formik>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Registration
```

I tried the code from above and im getting an error in my code this is my error looks like

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

[eslint] 
src\pages\Registration.jsx
  Line 55:5:  'imageHandler' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

why i got that error can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: Your question is due to a typo and has nothing to do with react, axios, or formik.  Add a `const` in front of `imageHandler` at the top of your code.  I'm making the assumption there's no additional relevant code you should have posted.

Comment: still got an error says 'handleChange' is assigned a value but never used

Comment: I Just edited to show all my codes.

Comment: It is extremely difficult to help when you keep changing the code you've posted and it requires different fixes.

Comment: i just change edit my code to show all my code

Answer (score 0):

I Solve the problem guys on how to upload image in reactjs frontend to backend using Formik i just did this code

```
{({
   setFieldValue
}) => (
   <Form>
       <label>Image</label>
       <ErrorMessage name="image" component="span"/>
       <input
            autoComplete="off"
            id="image"
            name="image"
            type="file"
            onChange={event => setFieldValue("image",event.currentTarget.files[0])}
       />
   </Form>
)}
```

I just declare the onFieldValue inside the Formik tag

In my backend API i did this

```
  const multer = require("multer");
  const path = require("path");

  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./Image",
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        return cb(null, 
 `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
        if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG)$/)) {
            req.fileValidationError = "Only the image file is allowed";
            return cb(new Error("Only the image file is allowed"), false);
        }
        cb(null, true);
    },
});

router.post("/", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
    const { 
            image = req.file.path,
            username, 
            password,
        } = req.body;
    bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hash) => {
        Admin.create({
            image: image,
            username: username,
            password: hash,
        });
        res.json("Success");
    });
});
```

I use multer library to get the image

i hope it helps to any one has same problem with me :)